# Rails Form Not hitting Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, routes

So, I have created an action in my transactions(tx) controller in order to update an order with an API call. The form is in the purchase confirmation page and its an ajax request.

```
def deduct_shipping_cost
  @transaction = Bid.find(params[:id]).tx
  if @transaction.update(transaction_params)
    @transaction.bid.shipping_cost = 0
    @transaction.bid.calculate_total_amount
    p @transaction.bid
    p ArmorPaymentsApi.update_order(@transaction.bid, "message" => "Buyer will be using their freight account #. Shipping costs that were quoted have been deducted from the order.")
  end
end
```

that is the action in my controller

```
post 'update_order' => 'transactions#deduct_shipping_cost', as: "deduct_shipping_cost"
```

that is the route

and here what the form looks like

```
.form-container
  = form_for(deduct_shipping_cost_path, html: { class: "inline-form" }, remote: true) do |f|
    .field.form-group.freight_num
      = f.text_field :shipping_account, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Account #"
    .actions.freight_num.send_ship_num{style: "margin-bottom: 20px;"}
      = f.submit 'Submit', class: "btn custom-btn"`
```

The server shows the data I am submitting but it doesn't update the `@transaction` nor does it do anything in the controller action

Comment: what is the result of `rake routes`

Comment: Also p statements outside of the if block, a ! after update to show if its validation errors, validation on models etc etc.

Comment: is it hitting the right action ?, what action do you see it gets executed ?, you will normally see the request in the console which indicates what I'm asking for, it's like this ControllerName#action, and then a lot of stuff. If it is hitting the right action, and you're not getting any errors, then you probably have a before_action which is preventing your action's code from being executed.

Comment: Started POST "/auctions/9/bids/14/purchase" for ::1 at 2016-08-12 11:29:11 -0400
Processing by AuctionsController#purchase as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "/update_order"=>{"shipping_account"=>"23423"}, "commit"=>"Submit", "auction_id"=>"9", "id"=>"14"}

Comment: Thats the console output. So I guess its not hitting the right action but i dont know why. the form has it right

Comment: form_for are used along with ActiveRecord objects, like form_for @transaction, you're not providing any object to it, what you're providing is the path. Try using form_tag http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag, more examples can be found here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: I had my path as
    post 'transaction/:id/update_order' => 'transactions#deduct_shipping_cost', as: "deduct_shipping_cost" with deduct_shipping_cost(@transaction) in the form and it didn't work either